# How to fix width and height of labels according to their text length?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two labels in a table cell. These labels' text sizes are not fixed as they come from a web service.

I want to set the height and width accordingly. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Simple add top, bottom, right, left constraint
2. Set no of lines of labels = 0
3. In delegate height for row at index path return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
4. For constraint issue set static height of one label and on attribute inspector make it greater than equal to in place of equal

Answer (score 0):

- Give top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints. Don't give height constraint.
- In attribute inspector, set lines to "0" and Line Break to "Word wrap".
- In tableView delegate heightForRowAtIndexPath return UITableViewAutomaticDimension